# 'ConfigureServices returning an System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.' in .NET Core 3.1 using Autofac

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to use autofac injection instead of default .net core solution.

Here is my startup file :

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false) ;
           

    var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
    cb.RegisterModule<mydependecymodule>();
    cb.Populate(services);
    var container = cb.Build();

    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}


// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)                           
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
         
    app.UseMvc(routes=>routes.MapRoute("default","/{controller=home}/{action=index}"));
}
```

And here is my program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
    
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    }).UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
```

But when I run my application I get this error in my main method:

`System.NotSupportedException: 'ConfigureServices returning an System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 the ASP.NET Core hosting model changed and you can't return an `IServiceProvider` anymore. [This is documented in the Autofac docs for integrating with ASP.NET Core 3.0+](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting).

You have to switch your `ConfigureServices` to be void, and if you want to register stuff directly with Autofac you need to use `ConfigureContainer`. You also need to register the `AutofacServiceProviderFactory` in your `Program.Main` method when you construct the host. There are examples in the documentation showing how to do this.

Comment: Thank you , I defined another container and it worked.